# Validation with Vue.js and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I am going to create a login mask with Firebase in the background, but I don't really know how I can verify the credentials of the user.

For example: The user is typing `administrator` and `password` in the fields and if in Firebase the Entry administrator and password contains the same key, the page will be shown.

Does someone know how I am able to 'search' for my input values to get the keys and compare them to validate?

I don't want to use the Firebase Auth0 - Systematic.

Answer (score 1):

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Directly from the official docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth